# Pagination with finder_sql defined with an association in a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a piece of code like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Some Code
  has_many :bars, finder_sql: proc{ "Valid SQL" }
  #Some more code
end
```

Now when I call foo.bar (where foo is an instance of Foo), how can I paginate the results, as bar is being fetched from the finder_sql? Is there any quick and easy way of doing it?

Comment: Can I do something with paginate_by_sql?

Answer (score 0):

Give [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) a try. It is a gem that helps with pagination and works really well. Not sure if it works with find_sql and associations, but it's worth a try. I know it works with scopes.

Comment: Thanks. I doubt if kaminari or will_pagintae can be used out of the box for this issue. I am trying various approaches though.